# How to call ONLY javascript function in html.actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have java script function

```
   function SetTextBoxValue(data) {
        $('#text_box').val($(this).val("myField"))

    };
```

Is it possible, and how, to call only this function, WITHOUT controller and action names from `@Html.ActionLink()` in razor view?

To  extend a question, i have table and a form with 4 text boxes on same view. I need to fill one textbox with a value of a specific column in table when user click on link in that column.

Comment: The script does not make sense (what is `$(this)` in the context of the function?). Show the html and indicate what your trying to do.

Comment: $(this) is @html.actionlink defined as "                    @Html.ActionLink(modelItem.myfield, "controller", "action"  new  { OnClick = "SetTextBoxValue()" })"

Comment: Why use `Html.Actionlink` if you only need js code to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "#", "", null, new { onclick="SetTextBoxValue('mydata')" });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, you have to do it as onclick="return SetTextBoxValue('mydate')"

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 steps :

1 : add onclick="return someJsFct" in your actionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("click here", "", "", null, new { onclick="return SetTextBoxValue('data')" });
```

2 : 
your javascript function must return false to prevent the actionLink from calling the server

```
<script language="javascript">
    function SetTextBoxValue(data) {
        // some code

        return false;
    }
</script>
```